# Running jstree for the first time

Tags: jstree

I'm new to both jQuery and jsTree and haven't much experience with html, CSS or Java Script either. Now, I'm trying to set up a little test tree in html list format.
This is my html list:

```
<div id="testtree">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Fruits and Vegetables</a>
          <ul>
        <li><a>Fruit</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Apple</a></li>
                <li><a>Banana</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a>Vegetables</a>
              <ul>
            <li><a>Zucchini</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jstree test</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm not sure where to insert the html list into the code and where to insert

```
$("#testtree").jstree();
```

I put all the jsTree files in the same folder as my html file (including _demo, _docs and _lib), not only the jquery.jstree.js file. The jQuery file that was included in the installation package of jsTree is working - I'm not sure if my code is wrong or if it's a problem with the jquery.jstree.js file.
Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Edit: It seems that jstree is not loading correctly, I added

```
alert($().jquery);
alert($().jquery.jstree);
```

to the code and get the version number for jquery (1.9.1) but 'undefined' for jstree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in when the document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testtree").jstree();
})
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vLH55/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where do I need to put the html list? Edit: Got it!

Comment: This does not solve the problem and also the fiddle does not even work, it just displays an unordered list.